# Xubuntu keeps loading on install with usb stick

Tags: installation, xubuntu

I'm trying to install Xubuntu on my computer. I've followed a guide to create a USB bootable drive.

I've inserted the USB stick and started the computer. I can see Xubuntu loading and after a minute or 2 it shows me a screen asking me if I'd like to use the live version or if I'd like to install. I choose install. Then on the next screen I select English as language. When I click continue, Xubuntu just keeps loading. It doesn't really freeze as I can still quit and move the cursor.

When I clicked quit, I see the live version and all is working just fine. I can browse the internet, etc.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Probably the installer wasn't properly copied/downloaded. Use a fresh iso, copy it to the USB drive with Unetbootin, then just boot.

Comment: I've tried 3 different isos already. The last two I checked had checksum errors. Although when I check the isos they match the ones in the Xubuntu MD5 checksum text files. I'm now trying the alternate 12.04 (which I've downloaded with the torrent file) but I'm getting this error when I check the iso before installing: "The ./pool/universe/s/synaptic/synaptic_0.75.9ubuntu1_i386.deb file failed the MD5 checksum verification. Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.

Comment: It means the ISO is corrupted. Something is interrupting your download.

Comment: @mattyh88 Please, respond confirming or refuting the issue. If the problem persist, add more information or comment any new problem. If it doesn't, tell us how did you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem too. The installer seems to stick when a USB device (like the one you want to install on) is connected. The following worked for me:

1. Boot from the USB and wait for the first window
2. Remove the USB drive
3. Click in `Install`, now it should move to the next screen.
4. Once you reach the screen with the installation options choose `Something Else`
5. Then insert your USB and click `next`

You will now have a list of all drives including your USB flash drive to install too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this wasn't the issue. I even tried using a dvd but the same problem occurred. For now I installed ubuntu desktop (using a dvd) and this works :)

Comment: +1 - Improving on the answer a bit, to get the `Something Else` option you have to "Try Xubuntu without Installing" at the boot menu. Then run the installer. - Also I am using a USB 3.0. When it was in the 3.0 slot it would not work, putting it in a 2.0 slot made it work just fine.